# Google Messenger - Cannot search thread

Tags: google-messages

My Google Messenger app will no longer let me search threads. One of the suggestions I found was to reinstall the app, but then I will lose the messages that I wanted to search.

[image: Screenshot of Messenger app]

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. Tldr: turn on permissions for services and google app.

Had to enable permission to contacts and sms for google services. Also would not work unless Google App had sms permission, but could turn this off after.